# Вызов c# функции из кода JS файла Views .cshtml на ASP NETCore

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp

Не понимаю как вызвать функцию c# из JS-кода файла Views .cshtml

Использую ASP.NETCore и создал два файла : **Index Controller.cs** и **List.cshtml** с простой функцией svg onclick

**List.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <svg width="100" height="100">
        <rect id="12332" fill="#080" width="100" height="100" onclick="test()" />
    </svg>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
        // Here c# func call
    }
</script>
```

**IndexController.cs**

```
public class IndexController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult List()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Хочу вызвать некую функцию Test() из C# при нажатии на svg фрагмент

Что я должен сделать? Какие services я должен подключить к своему проекту? Где я должен создать функцию C#?

Сейчас у меня есть только файл контроллера .cs и сервис MVC

---

Но моя главная цель - передать атрибут svg id функции Test() C# при нажатии на svg элемент, может есть другие способы как это сделать?

Comment: Sorry, this is StackOverflow part in the Russian language. You need https://stackoverflow.com/ to ask in English.

Comment: Понял, исправил на русский язык

Comment: А почему AJAX запрос на сервер не подходит?

Comment: Подскажи, пожалуйста, как его грамотно сделать?

Comment: [Использование ajax](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/10.8.php)